# How to opt out from Next.js v13 route cache?

Tags: http, next.js, next.js13

This is my `route.ts`:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { serializeError } from 'serialize-error';

export const GET = async () => {
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: serializeError(error),
    }, {
      status: 500,
    });
  }

  const response = NextResponse.json({
    status: 'OK',
  });

  response.headers.set('cache-control', 'no-store');
  response.headers.set('x-robots-tag', 'noindex');

  return response;
};
```

It seems no matter what headers I add to the response, the response is always cached.

Here is an example cURL request:

```
curl -v https://...
*   Trying 104.196.232.237:443...
* Connected to ray.run (104.196.232.237) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=ray.run
*  start date: May 27 01:05:38 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 25 01:05:37 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "ray.run" matched cert's "ray.run"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* h2h3 [:method: GET]
* h2h3 [:path: ...]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: ray.run]
* h2h3 [user-agent: curl/7.86.0]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x11e811400)
> GET /... HTTP/2
> Host: ray.run
> user-agent: curl/7.86.0
> accept: */*
>
< HTTP/2 200
< x-dns-prefetch-control: on
< x-frame-options: DENY
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin
< permissions-policy: camera=(), microphone=(), geolocation=(), interest-cohort=()
< strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
< vary: RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch, Accept-Encoding
< x-nextjs-cache: HIT
< cache-control: no-store
< content-type: application/json
< x-robots-tag: noindex
< date: Fri, 16 Jun 2023 00:56:58 GMT
< server: railway
<
* Connection #0 to host ray.run left intact
```

Is this just next.js blatantly ignoring the spec?

```
< x-nextjs-cache: HIT
< cache-control: no-store
```

Answer (score 1):

GET route handlers are cached by default, to opt out you have to use the `request` object in your GET route handler as a parameter

```js
export const GET = async (request: Request) => {
  // dummy usage of request
  const headers = request.headers;
  // ...
};
```

**You have to use it inside the body of your function**

Here are all the ways you can opt out of caching as listed in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#opting-out-of-caching)

- Using the Request object with the GET method.
- Using any of the other HTTP methods.
- Using Dynamic Functions like cookies and headers.
- The Segment Config Options manually specifies dynamic mode.